# How to solve normals artifacts?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, uv, normals

I tried to model something like a cog. I created one tenth of the cog, mirror modified on 2 axes and added a circular array modifier to get the final result, using the merge option.

When I import the final model in Substance Painter, it looks as if the normals were off on the big flat surface. At least that's how I interpret it:

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

I checked, and all of the selected vertices below are on the exact same Z. Not their median, but the individual values.

[image]

If I simply create a circle mesh and fill it, I get a perfectly flat mirror surface:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

Shading entirely smooth or flat doesn't seem to influence this issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the shading set to smooth (of the problem faces)?

Comment: @MrZak Should be flat. I added two images to my question. Once is shaded entirely flat, the other smooth. The artifacts are visible on both.

Comment: Try selecting all vertices and removing doubles ( W --> Remove doubles ). Seems to me you might have created quite a few doubles by modeling with the array modifier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an UV issue. I mapped identical parts of the cog to identical areas on the UV map. Substance Painter doesn't seem to like that. Unreal Engine doesn't seem to have this issue. I now applied all modifiers and smart UV unwrapped and I'm finally having no artifacts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer I created a Blender **add-on** for this exact purpose called [TiNA](https://gitlab.com/Modanung/TiNA) which allows you to more easily transfer normals between objects. TiNA basically turns the somewhat overwhelming [Data Transfer Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) into a set of more comprehensible operations.
There's a [special branch](https://gitlab.com/Modanung/TiNA/tree/b2.80) for those using Blender 2.80 beta.

[image: TiNA|]

```
 Hotkey           | Operation 
------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Alt+N            | Transfer Normals from selection to active object
 Shift+Alt+N      | Transfer Normals from active object to all other selected objects
 Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N | Clear Custom Normals data for entire selection
 Alt+W            | Wrap Normals
```

You can selectively transfer normals from a source object (possibly just a plane) by selecting both objects, and - with the target object as your active one - hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. You can then select a vertex group to limit the effect.

[image: Example results]